# Cache Files Not Found with Gatsby Source Contentful in Gatsby V4

Tags: caching, gatsby, netlify, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

### Context:

I've migrated my Gatsby project to the latest Gatsby Version 4 and use the new `gatsby-plugin-image` rather than the deprecated `gatsby-image`.

When I deployed to Netlify, I kept getting the same error below. However, in local development, everything is working.

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/.cache/caches/gatsby-source-contentful/xxsdfhsdkfh/myimage.png`

### What I've tried ( didn't fix the problem sadly)

1. Click the "Clear cache and deploy site" in Netlify
2. Deleted the `.cache` and `public` folder and `gatsby build`,
3. Updated some files and pushed the changes again

### Version / Dependencies

```
    "gatsby": "^4.0.1",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "6.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-graphql": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "3.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.0.0",

.. more
```

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind the path that is prompting the error (`.cache`):

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> `'/opt/build/repo/.cache/caches/gatsby-source-contentful/xxsdfhsdkfh/myimage.png`

I'd try to run a fresh deploy clicking the "Clear cache and deploy site"

Comment: The errors kept coming back. I've tried clear cache and deploy site a few times. Sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Change your build command to perform a `gatsby clean` before. Stuff like "sometimes work and sometimes not" are mostly related to cache issues